# AppCheck Debug Token for iOS not showing

Tags: ios, flutter, firebase, firebase-app-check

I'm developing a flutter application which uses Firebase as it's back-end framework. I've been developing the application for Android for quite some time, and recently I'm trying to support iOS as well. In my application, I do a call to Firebase RTDB to get some data, and I used await for it since I need it to be finished before performing other tasks. However, the fetch operation never finishes when I open it on iOS Simulator, it works fine when I use it in the distributed app on a real device. This didn't happen before I enforced App Check for my Firebase Project. Which convinces me that this problem is due to App Check. So I looked up on how to register my debug environment, which is provided here in the Firebase Docs. But, even after following the steps, I still can't get the debug token to show up in the terminal. Are there any steps that I might've missed? Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The solution that I found was that the debug token won't show up if I run it directly from Android Studio, however, if I run it using Xcode, it shows up. So I always use Xcode for the first run to register the debug token, after that I just proceed on using Android Studio as the debug token has been registered.

Comment: to get debug token showing in xcode, i followed the instructions at https://firebase.google.com/docs/app-check/flutter/debug-provider

key steps to Enable debug logging in your Xcode project (v11.0 or newer):

    (1) Open Product > Scheme > Edit scheme.
    (2) Select Run from the left menu, then select the Arguments tab.
    (3) In the Arguments Passed on Launch section, add -FIRDebugEnabled.

Answer (score 0):

I found an ostensible solution for testing on the iOS simulator when building out a native SwiftUI app. I assume you need to add some Swift code when building out AppCheck within Flutter. In the custom `AppCheckProviderFactory` that gets created for when the app check gets launched, you'll want to add some custom code to print out the `localDebugToken` of the simulator. Then, you'll store that in the device tokens under AppCheck in Firebase.

```
import Foundation
import FirebaseCore
import FirebaseAppCheck

class NativeAppCheckProviderFactory: NSObject, AppCheckProviderFactory {
    func createProvider(with app: FirebaseApp) -> AppCheckProvider? {
#if targetEnvironment(simulator)
    // App Attest is not available on simulators.
    // Use a debug provider.
    let provider = AppCheckDebugProvider(app: app)

    // Print only locally generated token to avoid a valid token leak on CI.
    print("Firebase App Check debug token: \(provider?.localDebugToken() ?? "" )")

    return provider
#else
    // Use App Attest provider on real devices.
    return AppAttestProvider(app: app)
#endif
    }
}
```

[Source](https://firebase.google.com/codelabs/app-attest#7)